# How to pass set of input files(not directory) to spark job and create dataframe on top of those files

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I would like to pass set of avro files as input to spark job and create dataframe on top of those files. (I don't want to place files in a directory and pass directory as input).

In Spark shell, I'm able to create dataframe successfully like below.

```
val DF = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/data/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_1.1569650402704.avro","/data/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_2.1569650402353.avro")
```

But the same is failing when I try to run through spark-submit command.

To pass the avro files independently to spark job, I'm trying to place avro files in a text file and pass this file as input argument to Driver class.

textFile:

```
/data/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_1.1569650402704.avro
/data/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_2.1569650402353.avro

spark-submit --class Spark_submit_test --master yarn Spark_submit_test.jar textFile
```

```
val filename = args(0)
val files = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
val fileList = files.mkString(",")
println("fileList : "+fileList)
```

=> This prints

```
fileList : /data/ASDS/PNR/archive/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_1.1569650402704.avro,/data/ASDS/PNR/archive/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_2.1569650402353.avro
```

```
val DF = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(fileList)
```

Getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://bdaolc01-ns/data/ASDS/PNR/archive/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_1.1569650402704.avro,/data/ASDS/PNR/archive/year=2019/month=09/day=28/hour=01/data_2.1569650402353.avro does not exist.
```

Not sure how I can avoid "`hdfs://bdaolc01-ns`" appending in beginning.
Please correct me if I'm doing wrong or suggest better approach for doing the same.

Note : I tried enclosing file names in double quotes, but no use.

**Expected Result :**
Dataframe should be created successfully and df.printSchema should list proper schema of the avro files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the input file path to spark-submit command with `--files` option.
Also pass the input file name as command line argument.
This way I'll be able to read the file in Drive class.

```
val avrofiles = Source.fromFile(inputFileName).getLines.toArray
```

And create a dataframe

```
val dF = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(avrofiles:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the splat operator!

> myList: _*

```
scala> val data = spark.read.parquet(paths: _*)
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, a: int ... 1 more field]    

scala> val paths = List("/tmp/example-parquet/part-00000-38cd8823-bff7-46f0-82a0-13d1d00ecce5-c000.snappy.parquet")
paths: List[String] = List(/tmp/example-parquet/part-00000-38cd8823-bff7-46f0-82a0-13d1d00ecce5-c000.snappy.parquet)

scala> val data = spark.read.parquet(paths: _*)
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, a: int ... 1 more field]

scala> data.count
res0: Long = 12500000
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply.
This solution might work for spark 2, that too for parquet. Unfortunately, we are still using spark 1.6. 
Could you please suggest any solution w.r.t spark 1.6

Comment: unfortunately only a few of the functions on the DataFrameReader are varyargs
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader